# Running MySql replication between datacenters

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication, database-administration, datacenter

I run my website from EC2. Due to AWS outages, I am contemplating replicating my setup on Rackspace and switch over from DNS in case of an outage.

I am looking to learn ways to replicate my MySql database across these data centers.

Can someone educate me about the methodology, costs, advantages and pitfalls in this approach?

My site serves around 30K users per day with around 30 GB of Database data.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/1274/mysql-replication-across-geographically-separate-servers

Answer (score 2):

Costs: Another server as hot standby

Advantages: Relativly simple approach, impact on current production system is low

Pitfalls:

- Takes some time to setup (you need to copy your whole database to Rackspace) in sync with binary log
- You also need to sync your web contents to the other data center (rsync might be enough)
- Replication can fall behind or even break, you need to monitor it
- You might want to consider to encrypt your communication to the other datacenter